# RDP from Windows 7 to Ubuntu Mavericks

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rdp

I have ubuntu maverick 10.10 running on rackspace.
Installed xrdp on it.

I try to connect from Windows 7 using RDP
The error I get says only 8 bpp and 16 bpp are supported.

Any help would be appreciated
Bala

Comment: Should take this over to http://superuser.com, or maybe http://serverfault.com but it might get closed there.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be your RDP client complaining that it is not able to match the bit depth.

When you launch RDP client before connection try this.  Expand 'Options',  go to display and change the bit depth in the colors section to 16.